# Lubuntu says battery is "fully charged" at 92 percent

Tags: lubuntu, battery, charging

When I leave my laptop connected to the charger, Lubuntu said the battery was fully charged. But, at the same time it said the battery was 92 percent charged. The charge indicator on my laptop (hardware), however showed it was still charging (it was orange: orange = charging & blue = charged). I don't know if it stopped charging though. How can I fix this?

Bottom right corner - the percentage would say 92% and "Charging" would be "Fully Charged": 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWmrK.png)

Comment: I wouldn't mind it, it doesn't seem to be a very big problem (to me). Also, does the screenshot say it's charging? I'm sorry if I'm not getting your point.

Comment: The screenshot just shows the charging when it didn't say fully charged. I just posted it so people would know what I'm talking about. In the post I said what would it look like if it was the problem I described. I posted the screenshot so people would get an idea of what I was talking about. I want to know if it is actually fully charged or if I should let it keep charging until the charge light turns blue.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for the misunderstanding! I'm not an expert on computer hardware, but it sounds like you would need a new driver. But again, I wouldn't worry too much if I were you.